# Unable to import psutil in python3 with cygwin [ImportError: no os specific module found]

Tags: python, pip, cygwin, python-3.8

I've been trying to import the psutil module from cygwin (as a Linux alternative for Windows 7). The installation worked, though.

When re-installed, it showed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1.3)
```

But when imported, it gave:

```
>>> import psutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
raise ImportError('no os specific module found')
ImportError: no os specific module found
```

I tried a couple of things:

1. Upgrading the pip and psutil itself, using these commands:

   ```
   python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
   pip3 install --upgrade psutil
   ```

   so the current version:

   ```
   Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (21.2.4)
   Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1.3)
   ```
2. Made sure that packages are installed only in the python 3.8.10 version (I have multiple versions of python installed, so I figured the inconsistency of versions may be causing the problem. But still, it didn't help).

   Though, what I've done so far is just making sure I'd type an extra "3" after each python-related command.

I'm still new to cygwin and python, any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong here, but I did some digging, and it looks like they have been trying add cygwin support for psutil since 2010, see github page for [psutil issue #82](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/82). Looks like there is no support for now.

Comment: Check the location of both python3 and pip3. They should be in the same Cygwin folder. A safe way to use pip is `python3 -m pip install - U psutil` e.g. Also use Cygwin setup to see if the is a binary package for psutil. I'm on phone now. You might need to install the Python wheel package -  look for it in Cygwin setup first, then with pip.

Comment: psutil does not support cygwin. Neither does pypsutil, although it will install and fail at runtime. Both should have some level of support as cygwin brings a POSIX environment to Windows.

Comment: If you would like Cygwin support for psutil please ask its author @giampaolo to unblock me from the project.  We had some fights over how to handle the Cygwin port, and it got a bit out of hand.  But when I came to him with mea culpas and offers to fully cooperate with his vision of the port, rather than keep an open mind he banned me from the project.  If you want you can still try my mostly completely port, but it's a few versions out of date as I haven't worked on it in the last ~year https://github.com/embray/psutil/tree/cygwin/v3

Comment: He also promised he would work on the port himself, but it never materialized.  So it's a shame this issue remains open when there's already an existing Cygwin implementation that's nearly complete...